# AVX2, How to Efficiently Load Four Integers to Even Indices of a 256 Bit Register and Copy to Odd Indices?

Tags: x86, sse, simd, avx, avx2

I have an aligned array of integers in memory containing indices I0, I1, I2, I3. My goal is to get them into a __m256i register containing I0, I0 + 1, I1, I1 + 1, I2, I2 + 1, I3, I3 + 1. The hard part is getting them into the 256 bit register as I0, I0, I1, I1, I2, I2, I3, I3, after which I can just add a register containing 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1.

I found the intrinsic, _mm256_castsi128_si256, which lets me load the 4 integers into the lower 128 bits of the 256 bit register, but I'm struggling to find the best intrinsics to use from there.

Any help would be appreciated. I have access to all SSE versions, AVX, and AVX2 and would like to do this using intrinsics only.

Edit:

I think this works, but I'm not how efficient it is...in the process of testing it.

```
// _mm128_load_si128: Loads 4 integer values into a temporary 128bit register.
// _mm256_broadcastsi128_si256: Copies 4 integer values in the 128 bit register to the low and high 128 bits of the 256 bit register.
__m256i tmpStuff = _mm256_broadcastsi128_si256 ((_mm_load_si128((__m128i*) indicesArray)));

// _mm256_unpacklo_epi32: Interleaves the integer values of source0 and source1.
__m256i indices = _mm256_unpacklo_epi32(tmpStuff, tmpStuff);

__m256i regToAdd = _mm256_set_epi32 (0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1);
indices = _mm256_add_epi32(indices, regToAdd);
```

Edit2: The above code does not work because _mm256_unpacklo_epi32 does not behave the way I thought. The code above will result in I0, I0+1, I1, I1+1, I0,I0+1, I1, I1+1.

Edit3: The following code works, though again I'm not sure if it's the most efficient:

```
__m256i tmpStuff = _mm256_castsi128_si256(_mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*) indicesArray));
__m256i mask = _mm256_set_epi32 (3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0);
__m256i indices= _mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32(tmpStuff, mask);
__m256i regToAdd = _mm256_set_epi32 (1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0); // Set in reverse order.
indices= _mm256_add_epi32(indices, regToAdd);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `_mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32` version looks ideal for Intel CPUs, unless I'm missing a way that could fold the shuffle into a 128b load.  That could help slightly for fused-domain uop throughput, but not for unfused-domain.

1 load (`vmovdqa`), 1 shuffle (`vpermd`, aka `_mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32`) and 1 add (`vpaddd`) is pretty light-weight.  On Intel, lane-crossing shuffles have extra latency but no worse throughput.  On AMD Ryzen, lane-crossing shuffles are more expensive.  (http://agner.org/optimize/).

Since you can use AVX2, your solution is great if loading a shuffle mask for `vpermd` isn't a problem.  (register pressure / cache misses).

Beware that `_mm256_castsi128_si256` doesn't guarantee the high half of the `__m256i` is all zero.  But you don't depend on this, so your code is totally fine.

---

**BTW, you could use one 256-bit load and unpack it 2 different ways with `vpermd`.**  Use another `mask` with all elements 4 higher.

---

**Another option is an unaligned 256b load with the lane-split in the middle of your 4 elements**, so you have 2 elements at the bottom of the high lane and 2 at the top of the low lane.  Then you can use an in-lane shuffle to put your data where it's needed.  But it's a different shuffle in each lane, so you will still need a shuffle that takes the control operand in a register (not an immediate) to do it in a single operation.  (`vpshufd` and `vpermilps imm8` recycle the same immediate for both lanes.)  The only shuffles where different bits of the immediate affect the upper / lower lane separately are qword granularity shuffles like `vpermq` (`_mm256_permutex_epi64`, not `permutexvar`).

You could use [`vpermilps ymm,ymm,ymm`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/VPERMILPS.html), or `vpshufb` (`_mm256_shuffle_epi8`) for this, which will run more efficiently on Ryzen than a lane-crossing `vpermd` (probably 3 uops / 1 per 4c throughput if it's the same as `vpermps`, according to [Agner Fog](http://agner.org/optimize/)

But using an unaligned load is not appealing when your data is already aligned, and all it gains is an in-lane vs. lane-crossing shuffle.  If you'd needed a 16 or 8-bit granularity shuffle, it would probably be worth it (because there is no lane-crossing byte or word shuffle until AVX512, and on Skylake-AVX512 `vpermw` is multiple uops.)

---

**An alternative that avoids a shuffle-mask vector constant, but is worse performance** (because it takes twice as many shuffles):

[`vpmovzxdq`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PMOVZX.html) is another option for getting the upper two elements into the upper 128bit lane.

```
; slow, not recommended.  Avoids using a register for shuffle-control, though.
vpmovzxdq  ymm0, [src]
vpshufd    ymm1, ymm0, _MM_SHUFFLE(2,2, 0,0)   ; duplicate elements
vpaddd     ...
```

---

Or, possibly higher throughput than the 2-shuffle version above if the shuffle port is a bottleneck for the whole loop.  (Still worse than the `vpermd` version, though.)

```
; slow, not recommended.
vpmovzxdq  ymm0, [src]
vpsllq     ymm1, ymm0,32          ; left shift by 32
vpor       ymm0, ymm0, odd_ones   ; OR with set1_epi64x(1ULL << 32)
vpaddd     ymm0, ymm0, ymm1       ; I_n+0 in even elements, 1+I_n in odd
```

This has some instruction-level parallelism: the OR can run in parallel with the shift.  But it still sucks for being more uops; if you're out of vector regs is probably still best to use a shuffle-control vector from memory.