# Using SIMD, how can I expand a 8-bit mask to 16-bit mask?

Tags: c, x86, simd, avx, avx2

I'm trying to rewrite this piece of code using simd:

```
int16_t v;
int32_t a[16];
int8_t b[32];
...
((int16_t *)a[i])[0] = b[i]==1? -v:v;
((int16_t *)a[i])[1] = b[i]==1? -v:v;
```

I was thinking of using `_mm256_cmpeq_epi8` to generate a mask vector, after that I can use `_mm256_and_si256` and `_mm256_andnot_si256` to perform the value choosing.

The trouble is b[i] is 8-bit integer while v is 16-bit. 

If the mask vector is like `{0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00...}`, it need to be expanded to `{0xffff, 0x0000, 0xffff, 0x0000...}` to perform the 16-bit value choosing.

How can I do that?
(Sorry for my English)

edit:
I found the solution with the inspiration from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38208501/avx2-how-to-efficiently-load-four-integers-to-even-indices-of-a-256-bit-registe).
The `_mm256_shuffle_epi256` can only perform within 128-bit lane.
So I broke the _mm256i mask into 2 _mm128i registers. Then with `_mm256_broadcastsi128_si256` and `_mm256_shuffle_epi256` I got the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a solution:

```
int16_t v;
int32_t a[16];
int8_t b[32];

//((int16_t *)a[i])[0] = b[i]==1? -v:v;
//((int16_t *)a[i])[1] = b[i]==1? -v:v;

__m256i _1 = _mm256_set1_epi8(1);
__m256i _b = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)b);

__m256i mask8i = _mm256_cmpeq_epi8(_b, _1); // 8-bit compare mask

__m256i permutedMask8i = _mm256_permute4x64_epi64(mask8i, 0xD8);
__m256i mask16iLo = _mm256_unpacklo_epi8(permutedMask8i, permutedMask8i); // low part of 16-bit compare mask
__m256i mask16iHi = _mm256_unpackhi_epi8(permutedMask8i, permutedMask8i); // high part of 16-bit compare mask

__m256i positiveV = _mm256_set1_epi16(-v); //positive mask condition
__m256i negativeV = _mm256_set1_epi16(v);  //negative mask condition

__m256i _aLo = _mm256_blendv_epi8(negativeV, positiveV, mask16iLo);
__m256i _aHi = _mm256_blendv_epi8(negativeV, positiveV, mask16iHi);

_mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)a + 0, _aLo);
_mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)a + 1, _aHi);
```

Comment: That looks like worse throughput and latency than `vpmovsxbw` for the low half plus `vextracti128`/`vpmovsxbw` for the high half.  Or do the compares 128-bit at a time, costing more loads.